# java Scanner input issues

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Im writing an assignment where i need to send email from my java program, I have everything set on my program but when i type my messeage in the program all im geting is the first word in the email i tried changing the  next to nextline but when i do that it doesnt even let me type anything but send the line automatically...
Any other guesses .... or ways ...tried with lists,arrays.
Problem with arrays is that i cant define the lenght of the message at the start of the program and i want to send the email once i hit return aafter i complete the email.

Answer (score 2):

You can try in this way:

```
import java.io.*;

public class test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;

    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of print statement in while loop you can do other stuff.